# Replacing emails in log file with their md5sum

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace, find

I am trying to replace the emails in the log file below with their md5sum instead of having them in plain text:

```
2021-09-26 03:52:29 email1@domain.com some_info1
2021-09-26 03:52:29 email1@domain.com some_info1
2021-09-26 03:53:11 email2@domain.com some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info
2021-09-26 03:53:11 email2@domain.com some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info
2021-09-26 03:55:32 email1@domain.com some_info1
2021-09-26 03:55:32 email1@domain.com some_info1
2021-09-26 03:56:11 email2@domain.com some_info2
2021-09-26 03:56:11 some_log_info
```

Using the bash script below, I end up with the wrong results and they are printed on stdout. I need the file content to be the same but with hashed emails.

```
#!bin/bash
cat sample.log | grep -Po "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}" | while read i ; do sed "s/$i/$(echo $i | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d ' ')/g"; done
```

Result

```
b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e
email2@domain.com
email2@domain.com
b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e
b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e
email2@domain.com
```

How can I change this to end up with the expected results in a new file?

```
2021-09-26 03:52:29 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:52:29 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:53:11 79f1af80136834378f073bab325f70af some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info
2021-09-26 03:53:11 79f1af80136834378f073bab325f70af some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info
2021-09-26 03:55:32 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:55:32 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:56:11 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info2
2021-09-26 03:56:11 some_log_info
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file always has space separated fields, and if email addresses are always the 3rd, like in the example you show, a simple `while - read` loop is an option. Example where the output is redirected to temporary file `file.tmp`:

```sh
$ while read -r d h e i; do
    if [[ "$e" =~ @ ]]; then
      m=($(md5sum <<< "$e"))
      e="${m[0]}"
    fi
    printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$d" "$h" "$e" "$i"
  done < file > file.tmp
$ cat file.tmp
2021-09-26 03:52:29 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:52:29 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:53:11 79f1af80136834378f073bab325f70af some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info 
2021-09-26 03:53:11 79f1af80136834378f073bab325f70af some_info2
2021-09-26 03:53:11 some_log_info 
2021-09-26 03:55:32 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:55:32 b063316737db418bb9d11bb938038b9e some_info1
2021-09-26 03:56:11 79f1af80136834378f073bab325f70af some_info2
2021-09-26 03:56:11 some_log_info
```

This assumes that any 3rd word containing a `@` character is an email address. Modify the regular expression in `[[ "$e" =~ @ ]]` if you need something more accurate.

If you are satisfied with the result rename the temporary file:

```sh
$ mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: Brilliant! However the output file is coming out empty, Is there something to do to fix it?

Comment: What output file? Please edit your question to clearly explain that you don't want the result to be sent on standard output but in a file, instead. Meanwhile, simply redirect the output to the output file you want (`done < file > file.out`).

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. See my updated answer for a way to modify the original file.